# Return varchar from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which returns an integer value.

Can I return a varchar instead of int ? Is there any way to return the varchar value to the calling procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of options:

Either use output parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx

or just `select` the varchar value at the end to return the data in a one-line/one-field table.

Answer (score 4):

```
select cast(123 as varchar(11))
```

Comment: You would need `11` to cope with all the range of -ve integers.

Answer (score 0):

It really escapes me why everywhere I turn nobody mentios the simple fact that you can just declare it like this

```
CREATE SP_foo
AS
  BEGIN
RETURN 'muajaja'
  END
GO
```

Than you can call something like this:

```
DECLARE @r varchar(255)
EXEC @r = SP_foo
```

I don't know if NOBODY mentions it like this because is probably not part of the T-SQL standard per-se? Even the MS docs says something [weird](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx):

> RETURN [ integer_expression ]
>
> **integer**_expression
>   Is the integer value that is returned. Stored procedures can return an integer value to a calling procedure or an application

But hey! as long as it works, right?

Comment: Downvotes aside, it 'does' work in MS SQL Server Express 2008 and above. Even if it's not part of the T-SQL Standard. I'm well aware of OUTPUT parameters. Just figured I would throw it out there.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in 2014 because it says it fails to convert the varchar to int